# Google Cloud ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Openlitespeed Server

Tags: virtual-machine, centos-7, google-cloud-platform

Im absoluty noob in this kinds of things, My VM is CentOS 7 and them I install Openlitespeed, I open port 80, also make the ip static, firewall is active, all seems fine but when I try access with my ip address say me ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  why? please help =)

Answer (score 1):

Please try `netstat -lnp | grep openlitespeed` to make sure OLS is up and running , also to what port it is listening.

then try `curl http://IP` and see what it returns.